# Save state for particular duration- android

Tags: android, savestate, android-framework

I have an android requirement where i have created a form like structure have radio buttons, edit texts and so on. When the user make half entries to the form and say moves away from the page either by back button or battery off. When he returns to the form, the same state of half filled form should re appear. Please suggest if android has internal functionality to save the form state and restore when the user revisits. Also, the stored contents should be saved only for particular duration say one hour after which the fresh form should appear. Please help with possible methods applicable for me to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading the Android Activity [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). From the webpage:

"In addition, the method [onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSaveInstanceState%28%29) is called before placing the activity in such a background state, allowing you to save away any dynamic instance state in your activity into the given Bundle, to be later received in onCreate(Bundle) if the activity needs to be re-created. See the Process Lifecycle section for more information on how the lifecycle of a process is tied to the activities it is hosting. Note that it is important to save persistent data in onPause() instead of onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) because the latter is not part of the lifecycle callbacks, so will not be called in every situation as described in its documentation."